# Proof $\mid(a - b)^{\frac{1}{n}}\mid \leqslant \mid a^{\frac{1}{n}} - b^{\frac{1}{n}}\mid$

Tags: binomial-theorem

We have $(a + b)^{n} \geq a^{n} + b^{n}$

Proof:

$\mid a - b \mid ^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq \mid \mid a \mid^{\frac{1}{n}} - \mid b\mid^{\frac{1}{n}}\mid$

Comment: What is $a$ and $b$ ? What is $n$ ?

Comment: a&b positive real numbers, n natural number*

Answer (score 0):

You can show this by using **induction**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description

I'll leave it to you to verify it using a base.

Now assume that

$\mid(a - b)^{\frac{1}{n}}\mid \leqslant \mid a^{\frac{1}{n}} - b^{\frac{1}{n}}\mid$ *(1)*

is true. We want to deduce that

$\mid(a - b)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\mid \leqslant \mid a^{\frac{1}{n+1}} - b^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\mid$  *(2)*

is true as well.

*Hint:* Try and see if you can rewrite *(2)* to *(1)* in some way and use your assumption. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Raising to the $n$-th power,
$|a - b|^{\frac{1}{n}} 
\geq || a|^{\frac{1}{n}} - |b|^{\frac{1}{n}}|
$
becomes
$|a - b| 
\geq || a|^{\frac{1}{n}} - |b|^{\frac{1}{n}}|^n
$.

Letting
$a = c^n$ and $b = d^n$,
this becomes
$|c^n - d^n| 
\geq || c| - |d||^n
$.

Assuming that
$|c| \ge |d|$,
dividing by $c^n$
and letting
$\frac{d}{c} = x$,
this is
$|1 - x^n| 
\geq |1 - x|^n
$.

Assume that $1 \ge x \ge 0$.
So we want to show that
$1-x^n \ge (1-x)^n$.

This is true for $x=0$
and $x=1$.

This is true for $n=1$.

Since $x^n$ and $(1-x)^n$
are decreasing
with increasing $n$,
$1-x^n$ is increasing and
$(1-x)^n$ is decreasing
so the inequality holds
for all $n$.